# How to prevent preview from discarding my PostScript constants defined in the preamble?

Tags: pstricks, best-practices, preview

### *Considerations:*

- I have to use `beamer` document class to create a step-by-step tutorial.
- I have to use `preview` package to trim everything outside `pspicture`.
- Using `standalone` document class is not possible because we cannot accomplish both requirements above.
- I have to define constants that must be available in both TeX and PostScript worlds.
- Constant declarations must not be verbose. A single declaration must provide a constant in both worlds at once.

### *What I have done:*

- I have defined (with the help of David Carlisle) a macro `\const[]{}{}` to defined a constant in both TeX and PostScript worlds at once. Please see the MWE below for the details.

### *MWE:*

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][6]{%
    \edef\temporary{trunc(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt

\const{Major}{3}% semi major
\const{Minor}{2}% semi minor

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-\Major,-\Minor)(\Major,\Minor)
    \pause
    \psellipse(0,0)(!Major Minor)% produces GhostScript errors
    %\psellipse(0,0)(!\Major\space \Minor)
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### *Problems:*

Compilation with GhostScript fails because all constants in PostScript world get discarded by `preview`.

### *Failed Solutions:*

- Moving

  ```
  \const{Major}{3}% semi major
  \const{Minor}{2}% semi minor
  ```

  from preamble to the body of `pspicture`

  ```
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-\Major,-\Minor)(\Major,\Minor)
      \const{Major}{3}% semi major
      \const{Minor}{2}% semi minor
      \pause
      \psellipse(0,0)(!Major Minor)% produces GhostScript errors
      %\psellipse(0,0)(!\Major\space \Minor)
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{frame}
  ```

  is not possible because the constants in TeX world must be accessible for `\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-\Major,-\Minor)(\Major,\Minor)`.

### *Bad Solutions:*

- Using `\psellipse(0,0)(!\Major\space \Minor)` instead of `\psellipse(0,0)(!Major Minor)` makes the RPN expressions cryptic.
- Using `\pstheader` is not convenient because I have to declare a single constant for each world manually.

### *Promising Idea:*

Edit `\const[]{}{}` implementation to create a new header file (if not exists) and append each PostScript constant to the the header file. Later this header file can be loaded with `\pstheader{}` macro.

### *Question:*

How to prevent preview from discarding my PostScript constants defined in the preamble while making my scenario done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save up your ps definitions and inject them inside the pspicture:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\pspicturedefs{\pspicturedefs
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\pspicturedefs{}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt

\const{Major}{3}% semi major
\const{Minor}{2}% semi minor

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-\Major,-\Minor)(\Major,\Minor)
\pspicturedefs
    \pause
    \psellipse(0,0)(!Major Minor)% produces GhostScript errors
    %\psellipse(0,0)(!\Major\space \Minor)
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```